# how to get swipeUp and swipeDown event?

Tags: jquery, swipe

Hello i'm using **swipe up** and **swipe down** function it's working on desktop but not working on mobile browser . So please suggest me how to fix it ? i don't wanna use jquery mobile .

Here is my jquery code .

```
var supportTouch = $.support.touch,
        scrollEvent = "touchmove scroll",
        touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
        touchStopEvent = supportTouch ? "touchend" : "mouseup",
        touchMoveEvent = supportTouch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";
$.event.special.swipeupdown = {
    setup: function() {
        var thisObject = this;
        var $this = $(thisObject);
        $this.bind(touchStartEvent, function(event) {
            var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                    event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                    event,
                    start = {
                        time: (new Date).getTime(),
                        coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ],
                        origin: $(event.target)
                    },
                    stop;

            function moveHandler(event) {
                if (!start) {
                    return;
                }
                var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                        event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                        event;
                stop = {
                    time: (new Date).getTime(),
                    coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ]
                };

                // prevent scrolling
                if (Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 10) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            $this
                    .bind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler)
                    .one(touchStopEvent, function(event) {
                $this.unbind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler);
                if (start && stop) {
                    if (stop.time - start.time < 1000 &&
                            Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 30 &&
                            Math.abs(start.coords[0] - stop.coords[0]) < 75) {
                        start.origin
                                .trigger("swipeupdown")
                                .trigger(start.coords[1] > stop.coords[1] ? "swipeup" : "swipedown");
                    }
                }
                start = stop = undefined;
            });
        });
    }
};

$.each({
    swipedown: "swipeupdown",
    swipeup: "swipeupdown"
}, function(event, sourceEvent){
    $.event.special[event] = {
        setup: function(){
            $(this).bind(sourceEvent, $.noop);
        }
    };
});

$(document).on('swipedown',function(){console.log("swipedown..");} );
$(document).on('swipeup',function(){console.log("swipeup..");});
```

here is [live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as88425/Q3d9H/36/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code relies on jquery mobile to set `$.support.touch` to determine what event to bind. Without jquery mobile this is undefined so...

```
touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown";
/* touchStartEvent will always = mousedown unless $.support.touch = true */
```

The following code will work in mobile, although I wouldn't recommend it. There really isn't a good reason not to use jquery mobile in this case. jQuery will handle cross platform/browser inconsistencies much better than you will and you can do a custom build of the library with only touch events for 8kb... That's like nothing, even AOL Dialup users would be like "woah that JS loaded really fast"

```
$.support.touch = true;
var supportTouch = $.support.touch,
        scrollEvent = "touchmove scroll",
        touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
        touchStopEvent = supportTouch ? "touchend" : "mouseup",
        touchMoveEvent = supportTouch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";
$.event.special.swipeupdown = {
    setup: function() {
        var thisObject = this;
        var $this = $(thisObject);
        $this.bind(touchStartEvent, function(event) {
            var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                    event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                    event,
                    start = {
                        time: (new Date).getTime(),
                        coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ],
                        origin: $(event.target)
                    },
                    stop;

        function moveHandler(event) {
            if (!start) {
                return;
            }
            var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                    event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                    event;
            stop = {
                time: (new Date).getTime(),
                coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ]
            };

            // prevent scrolling
            if (Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 10) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        $this
                .bind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler)
                .one(touchStopEvent, function(event) {
            $this.unbind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler);
            if (start && stop) {
                if (stop.time - start.time < 1000 &&
                        Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 30 &&
                        Math.abs(start.coords[0] - stop.coords[0]) < 75) {
                    start.origin
                            .trigger("swipeupdown")
                            .trigger(start.coords[1] > stop.coords[1] ? "swipeup" : "swipedown");
                }
            }
            start = stop = undefined;
        });
    });
}
};

$.each({
    swipedown: "swipeupdown",
    swipeup: "swipeupdown"
}, function(event, sourceEvent){
    $.event.special[event] = {
        setup: function(){
            $(this).bind(sourceEvent, $.noop);
        }
    };
});

$(document).on('swipedown',function(){console.log("swipedown..");} );
$(document).on('swipeup',function(){console.log("swipeup..");});
```